# NullPointerException when referencing toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have added a toolbar in my activity and am trying to access it in my fragment to change the title and icon for the back navigation, however i keep getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

When i run my app as well as a number of warnings about possible object being null. I know it has something to do with `getsupportactionbar`
however i cannot work out what i am doing wrong

Here is the code for declaring the toolbar in activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The code for referencing and changing the toolbar in fragment

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

And the code for declaring the toolbar in xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

I am using `appcompatactivity` if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you access the toolbar before view inflation which results in `NullPointerException`. And also since you are using support library you need to cast your toolbar to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. Here is a solution which may help:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);    

        return rootView;
}
```

Comment: if he has `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` then casting `(Toolbar)` is the same as `(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)` ... but yeah you are right

Comment: Thanks for your answer i was calling it after view inflation, however, i get error `cannot resolve method` for `setHomeAsUpEnabled`, can i not do this in the fragment?

Comment: @AlHennessey I updated my code and tested it in Android Studio but didn't get any error. Please try the edit

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i updated my code but i get a null pointer exception on the `displayShowHomeEnabled` line. However if i leave the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` and the `setSupportActionBar` line out, the back button appears, however it doesnt do anything when pressed

Comment: Solved it by setting the `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` in the activity on create and then just using lines like `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");` to chang it in activity. To solve my problem of the button not doing anything i added `OnBackPressed` line to `OnOptionsItemSelected` Thanks for your help tho

Comment: @AlHennessey if you want the Up button to do something you need to define in your manifest what the parent of your activity is. then if you press the button it will go back to the parent, otherwise it doesn't do anything

Comment: @Pooya i was trying to do this with fragments not activities.

Comment: @AlHennessey toolbars are actually for activities that's why you need to set the toolbar by calling getActivity().setSupportActionBar

Answer (score -1):

((Activity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: `Activity` has no method `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score -1):

Modify this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

to this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: then NPE will thrown from `toolbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` line